# Java class to a nested real time database

Tags: android, sqlite, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a structure in Real-time database that contains a nested field. How could I create the java class to be able to set and get data?

[This is my structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeqCw.png)

Comment: click on export json and provide the json

Comment: Just added the complete JSON.

Comment: So, you want to make POJO for the whole structure or extract a specific element raw?

Comment: I want get the whole data from "Eventos" to my java class.

Comment: You can easily map ur entire data into the given class hierarchy i just answered check it out

Comment: You can declare it as  Map<String, Object> and then parse the Object as a JSONObject

Comment: Nice man, I´ll try it.

Comment: U can also try creating an array of Participantes

Comment: I think you need to flatten your data because nesting data is difficult to retrieve. It might require you to nest Map objects. instead flatten your data by storing indicators which will determine whether a node is related to another node or not. You can follow this link: https://www.airpair.com/firebase/posts/structuring-your-firebase-data for a good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

As i see in your `Eventos` class you only have declared the fileds but in order to set and get them you need to create public `setters` and `getters`. This how it should look like:

```
public int getID_Evento() {
    return ID_Evento;
}

public void setID_Evento(int ID_Evento) {
    this.ID_Evento = ID_Evento;
}

public int getID_Usuario_Criou() {
    return ID_Usuario_Criou;
}

public void setID_Usuario_Criou(int ID_Usuario_Criou) {
    this.ID_Usuario_Criou = ID_Usuario_Criou;
}
```

This is an example for the first 2 fields. For the others you need to do it in the same way. If you are using `Android Studio`, just click `Alt + Insert`, choose `Getter and Setter` and than select all your fields.

Once you have the correct `setters` and `getters` you can use them in your code. To set your fields please use this code:

```
Eventos eventos = new Eventos();
eventos.setID_Evento(ID_Evento);
// and so on for the other fields
yourReference.setValue(eventos);
```

As you see, in the end we have used the `setValue()` to add the created object to your `DatabaseReference`.

To get data out you need to use a `listener` on the correct `DatabaseReference` and get data from the `DataSnapshot` like this:

```
Eventos eventos = dataSnapshot.getValue(Eventos.class);
int ID_Evento = eventos.getID_Evento();
```

In order to have that nested node in you POJO you need to add a new `Map`fied named: participantes like this:

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> participantes = new HashMap<>();
```

In order to set the value of that field you need also to create a public setter and a getter. To actually set the values in your code, please use the following code:

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> participantes = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, String> map =  = new HashMap<>();
map.put(id_Usuario, "1");
map.put(vnv, "1");
map.put(vnv_data, "05/05/2017");
participantes.put(userEmail, map);
yourRef.setValue(participantes);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Alex, thx for the answer, The class already has the getters and setters except to the nested field, this de very problem. How should the class looks like with the nested field? (I have updated the question).